# HTML Dom in Internet explorer , winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

Can you use Html DOM in a Internet explorer plug-in to...

1) write/Auto fill in a form? From variable value assigned by your program.

2) Read values in label? Textboxes? And use them in your program?

Or better to just write a winform with web browser control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A well described Browser Helper Object implemented in C#, designed to steal passwords, showing you how to use the DOM in the process is available in [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Attach_BHO_with_C_.aspx).  Of course, battling built-in IE security is yours to deal with.  A Winforms project that uses WebBrowser.Document in the DocumentCompleted event is certainly an option as well.  There are far too few details in your question to help you choose.

Comment: Would I be able to read dynamic built  dom ? i mean if the page inside the webbrowser build  html using ajax , will I be able to read it ?